# How to call different custom cells in one UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

When I try to run this program, I get an error: "Control may reach end of non-void function". Do you know how to fix this problem? When I try to put a return between the last 2 closing braces, it shows another error.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 UILabel *label;

 if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {

    static NSString *CellIdentifer1 = @"GameDetailsSetScoringCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer1];
            label = (UILabel *)[cell1 viewWithTag:0];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Standard Set: 3 Sets"];
    return cell1;
}


if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0) {
     static NSString *CellIdentifer2 = @"GameDetailsDateTimeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer2];

    label = (UILabel *)[cell2 viewWithTag:0];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"March 5, 2015 5:25"];
    return cell2; 
}
 if (indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 0) {

    static NSString *CellIdentifer3 = @"GameDetailsLocationCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell3 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer3];

    label = (UILabel *)[cell3 viewWithTag:0];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Bridgewater, NJ"];
    return cell3;
 }

 if (indexPath.section == 3 && indexPath.row == 0) {

    static NSString *CellIdentifer4 = @"GameDetailsMatchModeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell4 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer4];

    label = (UILabel *)[cell4 viewWithTag:0];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Normal Mode"];
    return cell4;
}


  if (indexPath.section == 4 && indexPath.row == 0) {

    static NSString *CellIdentifer5 = @"GameDetailsAdCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell5 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer5];

    label = (UILabel *)[cell5 viewWithTag:0];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"NO"];
    return cell5;

     }

  }
```

If I try to add a (return cell;) or even (return cell1;) between the last two closing brackets I get the error:

> Use of undeclared identifier 'cell'
>   or 
>   Use of undeclared identifier 'cell1'

Comment: FYI - you should use `if/else` statements here, not just a series of `if` statements.

Comment: Update your question with how you attempted to add a `return` at the end and what the error was.

Comment: You should have added "return nil;` after the last `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @matt +1 said you must return a value for each possible case. which you don't do when the program did not enter any of the if scopes. Well, thats impossible you think. but the comipler don't know that.

**I modified your code:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UILabel *label;

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {

        static NSString *CellIdentifer1 = @"GameDetailsSetScoringCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer1];
        label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:0];
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Standard Set: 3 Sets"];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifer2 = @"GameDetailsDateTimeCell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer2];

        label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:0];
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"March 5, 2015 5:25"];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 0) {

        static NSString *CellIdentifer3 = @"GameDetailsLocationCell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer3];

        label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:0];
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Bridgewater, NJ"];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 3 && indexPath.row == 0) {

        static NSString *CellIdentifer4 = @"GameDetailsMatchModeCell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer4];

        label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:0];
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Normal Mode"];
        return cell;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 4 && indexPath.row == 0) {

        static NSString *CellIdentifer5 = @"GameDetailsAdCell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer5];

        label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:0];
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"NO"];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: this is a new error. open a new question for it. this one answered and its error is gone

Answer (score 2):

The problem is just one of satisfying the compiler. *You* believe that you are covering every possible case and returning a cell under all circumstances, but the *compiler* doesn't know that. What if *none* of your `if` conditions succeeds? What if the index path row is *not* 0? What if the index path section is not 0 thru 4? You may think that's impossible, but the compiler doesn't think so. You need to return a cell in that situation too.

Comment: When i try to add an else clause, it displays the error, (expected expression). Do you know why?

Comment: Yes, I do. I can't actually see what you're doing when you "add an else clause", but that notion makes little sense given your current code, because it is not an if/else construct to start with, is it?